# How to prove that a parametric curve is the intersection of 2 surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

So I've been working on a way to prove rigorously that a parametric curve is the intersection of two surfaces but I'm unsure of how to show it

**Question**

Show that the curve with parametric equations

$$x(t) = cos(t)$$
$$y(t) = sin(t)$$
$$z(t) = sin^2(t)$$

is the equation of the intersection curve of the surfaces

$$z = x^2$$
$$x^2 + y^2 =1$$

**Solution Attempt**

The intersection curve of the two surfaces is all the points such that

$$\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | z = x^2,  x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$$

On the other and, we know that

$$z(t) = sin^2(t) = (sin(t)) ^2 = x^2(t) \iff z(t) = x^2(t), $$

and
$$x^2(t) + y^2(t) = cos^2(t) + sin^2(t) = 1 \iff x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 1$$

So we know that the parametric curve, whatever $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is, respect the constraints.

Therefore, if C is the parametic curve, then

$$C = \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 1, z(t) = x^2(t)\}$$

*Here is where I dont know how to continue*
 How do I know that it is exactly the intersection? In other words, how do I use $t$ to make a conclusion and show that it is exactly the intersection?

Thank you!

Comment: You’re right to realize that this does need to be shown.

Comment: Let the curve be $C$ and the surfaces be $S_1$ and $S_2$. You've shown that any point in $C$ is also in $S_1$ and $S_2$, i.e. that $C \subseteq S_1 \cap S_2$. What you have to show now is that $S_1 \cap S_2 \subseteq C$, that is, take any point $(x,y,z)$ in both $S_1$ and $S_2$ and show that there is a corresponding $t$ which maps to it.

Comment: You need to reverse $x$ and $y$ in those equations!

Answer (score 0):

Plug the curve $\langle\sin t, \cos t, (\sin t)^2\rangle$ into the equations for the surfaces. Once you do that, you'll see that the equations are true, proving the curve indeed lies on the intersection:
For example, you have: $z=x^2  \implies   (\sin t)^2 = (\sin t)^2 $
Then do the same thing for the other surface equation!